# required attribute name in <provider

Tags: android, apk

when i edit a game it has this error:

```
/data/data/com.gmail.heagoo.apkeditor.pro/files/UNKNOWN(1)/AndroidManifest.xml:45: Tag <provider> missing required attribute name.
```

I went to android leveloper looking for required attribute names but then it gives me crap.